# SAML IDP implementation to support multiple SPs in a single IDP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, saml, idp

I have been working with SAML IDP implementation using saml_idp gem in Ruby.

My user-management is already acting as IDP for a ServiceProvider. All the configuration is totally set for that Service Provider alone. Now, I want to support one more Service Provider where the configuration is different from the existing one.

The question is how would I support multiple SP with different signatures, certificates in IDP to act separately for different service providers.

I have **saml_idp_initializer.rb** in my project. As mentioned earlier, it is more specific to a SP.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround solution where I can set up the SAML IDP configuration in the runtime which solves serving the requests to SP by the new IDP configuration.